# Handling Json Response

Tags: angularjs, arrays, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

JSON:

```
 {
    "json": {
        "response": {
          "servicetype": "1",
          "functiontype": "10011",
          "statuscode": "0",
          "statusmessage": "Success",
          "data":{
                "roleid": 36,
                "rolename": "Product Managers",
                "divisionlabel": "Department ",
                "subdivisionlabel": "Category",
                "roleinformation": {
                  "QA": [
                    {
                      "White Box Testing": 0
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },

              {
                "roleid": 108,
                "rolename": "Teacher",
                "divisionlabel": "Class",
                "subdivisionlabel": "Div",
                "roleinformation": ""
              }
            ],
            "unassignedroles": [
              {
                "roleid": 36,
                "rolename": "Product Managers",
                "divisionlabel": "Department ",
                "subdivisionlabel": "Category",
                "roleinformation": {
                  "QA": [
                    {
                      "White Box Testing": 0
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },

              {
                "roleid": 108,
                "rolename": "Teacher",
                "divisionlabel": "Class",
                "subdivisionlabel": "Div",
                "roleinformation": ""
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Above is my JSON response. I did concatenation for both `unassignedroles[]` and `assignedroles[]` to make single array. And then moved them into a dropdown. But when `rolename` is selected in dropdown, I need to populate `roleinformation` of that `rolename` in a table. If Product Managers is selected, the table should have Maximum values as 0 (`"White Box Testing": 0`). I have done till drop down box but couldn't assign values to table dynamically, when role is changed.

JS:

```
UserService.getAssignRoles(json).then(function(response) {
  if (response.json.response.statuscode == 0 && response.json.response.statusmessage == 'Success') {
    $scope.model.assignroles = [], assignrolesArray = [];

    var unasresdata = response.json.response.data.unassignedroles;
    var assresdata = response.json.response.data.assignedtoles;

    assignrolesArray = unasresdata.concat(assresdata);

    scope.model.assignroles = assignrolesArray;

    scope.model.rolename = assignrolesArray[0].rolename;

    for (var i = 0; i < assignrolesArray.length; i++) {
      console.log($scope.model.rolename);
      console.log(assignrolesArray[i].rolename);
      if (assignrolesArray[i].rolename === $scope.model.rolename) {
        console.log("success");
      }

    });
```

HTML:

```
  <select class="form-control" ng-model="model.selectedValue" name="groupzname" ng-change="getselectval(model.selectedValue)" readonly disabled>
    <option ng-repeat="item in model.dropDownData track by $index" value="{{item}}">{{item}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <select class="form-control" name="role"
      ng-model="model.rolename"
      ng-change="getassignRole(model.rolename)">
    <option selected>Select Roles</option>
    <option ng-repeat="role in model.assignroles track by $index"
        value="{{role.rolename}}">{{role.rolename}}</option>
    <table  ng-repeat="role in model.assignroles track by $index" >
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>{{maxCount}}</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
```

Comment: it would be helpful to see a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) to see your code in action :)

Comment: can you provide valid json? thanks

Comment: Your code is kind of all over the place, with a lot of syntax errors and invalid code. Clean that up, preferably in a [mcve], and we might be able to help you.

Comment: maybe a plunkr or something?

Comment: Hi , I pass request by help of service from backend. I just put the code in plnkr. But its not executing , due to lack of request.http://plnkr.co/edit/TQP32n79AdsEyCFGPY2s?p=preview